# encrypt PBEWithMD5AndDES in j2me

Tags: java-me, md5, plaintext, encryption

i'm triing to get this code to work on j2me
(it is working a java program)
but not yet in j2me

```
    public static String generate(String plaintext, String passphase) throws Exception {
        try {
            PBEKeySpec pbeKeySpec = new PBEKeySpec(passphase.toCharArray());
            PBEParameterSpec pbeParamSpec;
            SecretKeyFactory keyFac;
            // Salt
            byte[] salt = {(byte) 0xc8, (byte) 0x73, (byte) 0x61, (byte) 0x1d, (byte) 0x1a, (byte) 0xf2, (byte) 0xa8, (byte) 0x99};
            // Iteration count
            int count = 20;
            // Create PBE parameter set
            pbeParamSpec = new PBEParameterSpec(salt, count);
            keyFac = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBEWithMD5AndDES");
            SecretKey pbeKey = keyFac.generateSecret(pbeKeySpec);
            // Create PBE Cipher
            Cipher pbeCipher = Cipher.getInstance("PBEWithMD5AndDES");
            // Initialize PBE Cipher with key and parameters
            pbeCipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, pbeKey, pbeParamSpec);
            // Our cleartext
            byte[] cleartext = plaintext.getBytes();
            // Encrypt the cleartext
            byte[] ciphertext = pbeCipher.doFinal(cleartext);
            return ciphertext;
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            throw new Exception(ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

i found this lib
http://www.bouncycastle.org/java.html

the important thing is that i find a method for j2me that can encrypt using PBEWithMD5AndDES

anyone know the solution?

*edit adding extra info*

when i try to add the above code to a mobile project
following classes are not recognized (not included in j2me)

```
    PBEKeySpec
    PBEParameterSpec
    SecretKeyFactory
```

so i need a package that allows me to encode plain text using PBEWithMD5AndDES
anyone know such a package compatible with j2me?

thx for the replies so far

Answer (score 1):

A lot can go wrong when applying a primitive, you should use [Jasypt](http://www.jasypt.org/).

Comment: @Berty it is j2me compatible but it has its own implementation,  using modern primitives.  md5 and des are very old,  broken, and shouldn't be used by anyone.

Comment: @Rook thx for your reply.  i know they are not very safe, but they don't need to be, i just use them to generate a semi random password starting from some readable information. i already created a desktop installation and its in use now, so the mobile application has to be the same algorithm or the passwords won't match.  is it possible with the suggested package?

Comment: @Berty You just need a random number generator for that.  Using md5 and des is overkill.

Comment: i know. the point was that you can only generate the passwords if you have a passphrase.   this doens't matther cause i need to get it exacly the same as the desktop app, it has already been used to generate several passwords.

Comment: @Berty okay so you should post more information,  whats problem are you running into if you try and run this as j2me?

Comment: @Rook added extra info in original question